# Wildcard search in a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, 2013

In the default "find an item" search box in a SharePoint 2013 list, how do you get wildcard searches to work?

It seems that typing in things like an asterix will mean that SharePoint tries to find an actual asterix in the string instead of using wildcard logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When you use words in a free-text KQL query, Search in SharePoint 2013 returns results based on exact matches of your words with the terms stored in the full-text index. You can use just a part of a word, from the beginning of the word, by using the **wildcard operator (*)** to enable **prefix matching**. In prefix matching, Search in SharePoint 2013 matches results with terms that contain the word followed by zero or more characters.

For example, the following KQL queries return content items that contain the terms "federated" and "search":

```
federated search 
federat* search 
search fed*
```

KQL queries don’t support suffix matching, meaning that you can't make the same search like the following:

```
*erated search      #WRONG
search *ted         #WRONG
```

Reference: [Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx)

Comment: Well that answers part of the question. Thanks. Now how do you get suffix matching to work OOB? Or do you need to write code?

Comment: @zoonosis That's right, you need to code if you want suffix matching to work. Something we do a lot here :-)

Comment: Hi @BennySkogberg, can you explain more what API you use to do suffix matching? the FQL or search web service API? I cannot find any documentation of that supports suffix matching